# enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later

Tags: xcode, cordova, meteor, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

I am unable to implement push notifications. I get an error `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.`

I have Meteor app with [raix:push](https://github.com/raix/push) package. There are some duplicate questions but I haven't find any Cordova related. I know nothing about Objective-C so I'd prefer something else but actually any hack I can implement is enough.

Here is my repo https://github.com/mvaisanen/simplepushapp

Comment: open an issue on the raix push to update his push plugin to support iOS 8